# Null pointer exception inside generated IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice, android-annotations

I'm using AndroidAnnotations and I have a few IntentServices. I sometimes get this error (happens on all Services, not just the one below):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object reference
       at xxxx.DataLoaderService_.onHandleIntent(DataLoaderService_.java:51)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

But I can't check if Intent is null because `DataLoaderService_` is generated and not editable.

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: This is an example of how this service gets called:

```
DataLoaderService_.intent(MyApplication.getContext()).loadMyData().start();
```

And this is the service (generated):

```
@Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        DataLoaderService_.super.onHandleIntent(intent);
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_LOAD_MY_DATA.equals(action)) {
            super.loadMyData();
            return ;
        }
}

       public static class IntentBuilder_
            extends ServiceIntentBuilder<DataLoaderService_.IntentBuilder_>
        {
        public DataLoaderService_.IntentBuilder_ loadMyData() {
                    action(ACTION_LOAD_MY_DATA);
                    return this;
                }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code that invokes this IntentService.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Ironman I know how to fix the error inside normal class, but this is happening inside a generated class.

Answer (score -2):

your intent has a null  value.
use this code instead:

```
if (intent != null) {
 String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_LOAD_MY_DATA.equals(action)) {
            super.loadMyData();
            return ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I can do this inside a generated class that I can't change? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: i do not know your code. so, read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421430/reasons-that-the-passed-intent-would-be-null-in-onstartcommand and this