# How to pass along extra values to a service with START_STICKY?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my Android app I have a service which should be restarted automatically after it gets killed. I found out that this can be done using `START_STICKY`.

But apparently when the service is automatically restarted, the intent is `null`. The problem however, is that the intent is used to pass along a value. See the example below:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static final String MY_STRING_HANDLE = "MyString";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        // Read my string from intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); // ERROR: Intent can be null
        if (extras == null) {
            throw new Error("Intent did not contain my string");
        }

        String myString = extras.getString(MY_STRING_HANDLE);
        if (myString == null || myString.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Error("Intent did not contain my string");
        }

        // Do something with my string
        doSomeThing(myString);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

So usually I start the service like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra(MyService.MY_STRING_HANDLE, "Example string");
activity.startService(intent);
```

This works, but when the service is killed and automatically restarted I get the following result:

> **java.lang.NullPointerException:** Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

So my question is: If I cannot use intents, then how should I pass on values (i.e. `myString`) to my service?

---

*Regarding possible duplicate: My question is not about why the intent is `null`, it's about how I can handle this.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reasons that the passed Intent would be NULL in onStartCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421430/reasons-that-the-passed-intent-would-be-null-in-onstartcommand)

Comment: @ADM Please see the note below my question.

Comment: Yeah now you put it . Well you already have the answer below and in above link also.  yet again By CommonsWare...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` instead of `START_STICKY`. Also, make sure that for each `Intent` that you completely process, call `stopSelf()` with the ID value supplied in the corresponding call to `onStartCommand()`.

Then, if Android terminates your process (e.g., low memory), Android will restart your service and deliver to you any `Intent` objects that you did not indicate (via `stopSelf()`) that you processed.

---

Alternatively, do not rely on `Intent` extras. Instead, store your data in a file, database, `SharedPreferences`, server, etc., and have your service fetch the data from there.