# Android service crash when use kotlin language

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I am writing an android app with firebase and kotlin. Now I created a **kotlin class** that extends `Service` class.

*The problem is*, after start service if I close the app it **crashed**!

If I write same code with **java** all working fine! I can't understand why it crashed when I use **kotlin**?

Look my code bellow.

**myService.kt**

```
class myService : Service() {
    internal var TAG = "tagForLogD"

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d(TAG, "myService Created!")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d(TAG, "myService destroyed")
    }
}
```

**myService.java**

```
public class myService extends Service {
    String TAG = "tagForLogD";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "myService Created!");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "myService destroyed");
    }
}
```

Thank you for your support.

**Logcat throw bellow exception**

```
03-10 15:13:53.847 4911-4911/net.beingup.simplechat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.beingup.simplechat, PID: 4911
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service net.beingup.simplechat.Notification.myService@11a4382f with null: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter intent
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3975)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1842)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter intent
        at net.beingup.simplechat.Notification.myService.onStartCommand(myService.kt)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3958)
```

Comment: Please put the full stacktrace here.

Comment: There are no more code in my service.

Comment: There will a stacktrace printing in the console for this code. I have asked for error stacktrace, not code.

Comment: please look above. I add the stacktrace.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You declared `intent` to be non-null in `onStartCommand`:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int
```

> Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter intent

So instead declare it as `Intent?`.

[Reasons that the passed Intent would be NULL in onStartCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421430/reasons-that-the-passed-intent-would-be-null-in-onstartcommand)

Comment: How did you solve it? I cannot mark this as Intent? as otherwise "it overrides nothing"

Comment: @ligi the intent itself is declared as nullable. Maybe you're overriding a custom superclass...

Comment: yes - I was running into this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144442247

Comment: This fixes the issue !!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `LifecycleService` then this issue was [fixed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/3aba26f29d79b7b13038b06672ffb7554a5bc45a) in version 2.2.0-alpha02 of AndroidX Lifecycle library.

You can override:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int
```

(Notice: `Intent?` instead of `Intent`)

Answer (score 0):

Google fixed this bug in `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.2.0`;

[image: code]